# Linq if else condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

How can I merge this below query into a single query? I think multiple if's will add unnecessarily to code complexity.

```
var query = scenario.Where(x => x.ScenarioNumber == ScenarioNumber).Select(x => x).Distinct().ToList();

// Match exception number else return wild card entries.
if(query.Any(x=>x.ExcepNumber == ExcepNumber))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.ExcepNumber == ExcepNumber).ToList();
}
else
{
   query = query.Where(x => x.ExcepNumber == "**").ToList();
}

// Match regime else return wild card entries.
if (query.Any(x => x.Regime == Regime))
{
     query = query.Where(x => x.Regime == Regime).ToList();
}
else
{
     query = query.Where(x => x.Regime == "**").ToList();
}
finalResponse = query.Select(x => x.TestColumn).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: With linq you have to use (condition)? true : false

Comment: off topic but, 1) the select in the first query is superfluous. 2) after the first `ToList` call you have actually a real list in memory, so you need the `ToList` call again only in the last final line

Comment: Thanks @jdweng can you please elaborate more? As to how I can use it with above e.g

Comment: What jdwebg is suggesting is using [the ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: Try following : var query = scenario.Select(x => x).Distinct().Where(x => ((x.ScenarioNumber == ScenarioNumber) || (x.ExcepNumber == "**")) && ((x.Regime == Regime)) || (x.Regime == "**")))

Comment: When you say that you want to merge this to a single query, do you mean that you want the query to be executed at once or that you want the code to be more short/readable?

Comment: @jdweng This doesn't do the same thing because it will return both wild cards and the searched properties

Comment: @asaf92 I mean to make code more short/readable. Because every if is adding to the cyclomatic complexity of the code.

Comment: You can miss entries with `Regime` that matches your `Regime` if they get filtered by the first query. Is this intentional?

Comment: You queries are in series and does exactly what I suggested.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng I will try it out

Comment: @asaf92, Basically what I am doing if my Regime = 3, and my table also has matching 3's then return all rows with matching 3's otherwise return rows which has "**"

Comment: Yes but you're filtering both `ExceptNumber` and `Regime`, but if you have an entry `x` where `x.ExceptNumber != ExceptNumber` but `Regime == 3`, you won't have it in your final results

Comment: @asaf92 lets say ExceptionNumber=4, Regime=3 . If for a particular case x.ExceptionNimber !=4 the query will go to else block and filter out all rows having x.exceptionnumbrr=**. Now from those rows i am filtering rows with Regime=3 if it exists otherwise i am filtering x.Regime=** so its like a wild card match if exact value matches return it otherwise return all wildcard matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a suggestion. You could extract it into a generic method, in which you would pass a selector function which specifies the property to be used for the filtering and the 2 choices that you would like to be compared (and the collection of course).

```
private List<T> EitherFilterOrWildCard<T>(Func<T, string> selector, string compare, string elseCompare, List<T> query)
{
    var temp = query.Where(x => selector(x) == compare);
    
    return temp.Any() ? temp.ToList() : query.Where(x => selector(x) == elseCompare).ToList();
    
}
```

Your if statements would then shrink to these 2 lines:

```
query = EitherFilterOrWildCard<MyClass>(x => x.ExcepNumber, ExcepNumber, "**", query);
query = EitherFilterOrWildCard<MyClass>(x => x.Regime, Regime, "**", query);
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @mong zhu

Comment: @SushmaChaudhary glad I could help. You could actually even make it more general by introducing a second generic parameter for the type of the compared variable. This version here can only compare strings.